# Intel App-Porter, Apportabe, StellaSDK

Tags: android, ios

I have an iOS app that I want to convert to Android, it mostly uses UITableView, and other basic UI Objects, but other than that nothing fancy.

There are several tools out there that claim it can translate iOS to Android automatically.

I personally tried Apportable, StellaSDK, and also Intel App-Porter, but I didnt get any of them to work, even if I tried it with the simplest possible "hello world" iOS app using XIB.

Has anybody ever tried these or any other tool, that converts iOS apps to Android successfully for any non-game iOS app?

Thanks
rough

Answer (score 0):

**As of January 2014:**

In any case it's never "automatic", there is always some amount of work involved, as these porting kits always lag behind Apple and their implementations are incomplete.

Apportable: promising, but despite what their web site is saying it's not quite there yet, still under development (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/apportable-discuss)

Right now trying StellaSDK with no luck: samples don't work or don't compile and there is virtually no information on the 'Net, even here on SO. The only thing these sample apps seem to be able to do is to ping home (morningtec.cn) when you run them, and I don't think you can disable this easily.

App Porter: never tried but I don't believe auto-translating ObjC to HTML5 is such a great idea on many levels.

Yeah, the picture is grim.